# Can you cast a Patronus Charm in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

Is it possible to use the Patronus Charm in Hogwarts Legacy? If yes, then where and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

According to an article on [videogamer.com](https://www.videogamer.com/guides/is-there-patronus-in-hogwarts-legacy/) and [GameSpot](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/hogwarts-legacy-patronus-can-you-get-spell/1100-6511351/), the Patronus charm is not featured in Hogwarts Legacy.